# How can I determine the overall Cox proportional hazard HR in multivariate analysis?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, survival, cox-model, multivariate-regression

I am using the `survival` and `survminer` packages in R. I use the data and code below as an example. See also the output below. I can see the three overall multivariate p values of p=1e-06.

I also see the univariate HR and 95% CIs of the individual parameters. However, there is no overall multivariate HR and 95% CIs. How can it be determined?

Thank you.

```
 library("survival")
 library("survminer")
 data("lung")
 res.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + ph.ecog, data =  lung)
 summary(res.cox)
 # Call:
 # coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + ph.ecog, data = lung)
 #
 #   n= 227, number of events= 164 
 #    (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
 #
 #              coef exp(coef)  se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
 # age      0.011067  1.011128  0.009267  1.194 0.232416    
 # sex     -0.552612  0.575445  0.167739 -3.294 0.000986 ***
 # ph.ecog  0.463728  1.589991  0.113577  4.083 4.45e-05 ***
 # ---
 # Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
 #
 #         exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
 # age        1.0111     0.9890    0.9929    1.0297
 # sex        0.5754     1.7378    0.4142    0.7994
 # ph.ecog    1.5900     0.6289    1.2727    1.9864
 #
 # Concordance= 0.637  (se = 0.025 )
 # Likelihood ratio test= 30.5  on 3 df,   p=1e-06
 # Wald test            = 29.93  on 3 df,   p=1e-06
 # Score (logrank) test = 30.5  on 3 df,   p=1e-06
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be, because it makes no sense.

The hazard ratio is per unit of the independent variable. They can't be combined in any general fashion.

You can, however, compute hazard ratios to compare any two combinations of variables, e.g. a 42 year old woman with ph.ecog of 2.8 to a 54 year old man with a ph.ecog of 3.5. You can  do that using the parameter estimates in a formula. You can also get R to do it for you using `predict.coxph`

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. I see it reported in the literature sometimes, but maybe I am misunderstanding the meaning of it.